# Как обрабатывать такую кнопку

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте,я по нажатию кнопки создаю новые div,внутри которых кнопка. Подскажите,пожалуйста как мне ее обрабатывать?

```
$("#btn2").click(function () {

        var dynDiv = $('<div>')
            .attr('id', 'div_' + dname_id++)
            .css({
            'width': '50px',
                'height': '20px'
        })
            .addClass('resize')
            .html("<button id='dbtn' >click</button>");

        $('#dbtn').click(function () {alert("ghj")})


        $('#container').append(dynDiv);
        //-------------------------------------------------------//

        dynDiv.click(function () {

            $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');


        });

    });
```

Пробовал,но безуспешно.Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Динамически добавляемые элементы могут быть подписаны на события с помощью 
функции jQuery **.on** 
'`$(selector).on('eventname', function(e){ ...` '

```
var dname_id = 1;

$("#btn2").click(function () {

var dynDiv = $('<div>').attr('id', 'div_' + dname_id++)
    .css({
    'width': '50px',
        'height': '20px'
}).addClass('resize').html("<button id='dbtn' >click</button>");


$('body').append(dynDiv); //1. append html fragment to DOM

// 2. add event listener     
$('#dbtn').on('click', function () {
    alert("ghj");
});

dynDiv.click(function () {
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
 });
});
```

рабочий пример: http://jsfiddle.net/93m1fLzr/1/

Comment: А если, например,объекты ,это подгруженные ajax изображения на страницу как их обрабатывать? Клик понятно,также,а если мне нужно например такое $("img").resizable();Это на ajax изображения не работает

Answer (score -1):

Надо примерно так:

```
$('body').on('click', '#dbtn', function(){
alert('good');
})
```

но если кнопок много то тебе нужно клас юзать вместо id

Comment: Спасибо,очень помогли!

Comment: Не за что, всегда рад )